# Link extracted with BeautifulSoup won't equate with the same string

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using a combination of the BeautifulSoup and Requests packages to make a simple web-scraping script.

Using the Requests package, I make a response object of the homepage and read the text attribute to text file. Then, using BeautifulSoup, I filter out every single link in the text file from the  text attribute from the response object and append them all into a list.

```
url = 'http://sssscomic.com/' 
r = requests.get(url)
most_recent = r.text

with open('text.txt') as f_obj:
    f_obj.write(most_recent)

links = []

with open('text.txt','r') as f_obj:
    text = f_obj.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Now here's the kicker. When links is printed, it returns the following:

```
['comic2.php?page=321', 'http://sssscomic.com/', 'comic.php?page=1', 'https://twitter.com/sssscomic', 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stand-Still-Stay-Silent-webcomic/655890117765567', 'https://www.instagram.com/hummingfluff/', 'https://www.twitch.tv/hummingfluff', 'http://sssscomic.com/ssss-feed.xml', '?id=about', '?id=archive', '?id=characters', '?id=misc', 'https://hivemill.com/collections/stand-still-stay-silent', 'http://sssscomic.com/comic.php?page=1', 'https://hivemill.com/collections/stand-still-stay-silent', 'https://hivemill.com/collections/stand-still-stay-silent']
```

The first item on the list is `comic2.php?page=321` which is exactly what I'm looking for, and yet when I save it to a variable and compare it against the results of this list, the computer doesn't recognize them as equal.

```
last_recent = 'comic2.php?page=321'

if last_recent == str(links[0]):
    print('This should be triggering') 
if last_recent != str(links[0]): 
    print('But instead this is')
```

I don't know whats happening here, but it happens with every other site I've tried it with. I'm not well versed in arcana of html or the BeautifulSoup library but I suspect the issue lies within one of those realms. Or I could be completely wrong, I'm still very new at this. Anyone have an idea of whats going on?

Comment: is it python 2 or 3?

Comment: it's python3, and I'm using the newest version of BeautifulSoup

Comment: instead of checking for equality, try printing both values, `str` and `repr`. You might see some differences.

Comment: It will raise exception when I run the first example code.

Comment: hjpotter92 caught it! last_recent actually had a '\n' on the end of it when viewed with repr. I think this is because in my script, I'm actually assigning that variable by reading from another text file. Any idea why the '\n' is attaching itself to the string stored in the file?

Comment: depends on how the file was written. You can use [`.strip()`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.8/library/stdtypes#str.strip)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got it.

Thanks to hjpotter92 for pointing out the repr() method. I was actually reading last_recent from a file and because of this, it was adding an extra '\n' to the end of the string which str() wasn't showing.